# ios CLGeocoder. Asynchronous geocoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

Let's say I have a few addresses. I need to get the coordinates for each address in the cycle. But getting the coordinates for one address takes some time. How to get the coordinates asynchronously in one cycle?

Comment: The number of "how to do" question has increased. If you don't find anything you can still ask, but please at least search the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a routine that geocodes a single address from a mutable array and then have it call itself to process the next one in the completion block. Thus:

```
- (void)nextGeocodeRequest {
    // if we're done, dp whatever you want

    if ([self.addresses count] == 0) {
        // do whatever you want when we're done (e.g. open maps)

        return;
    }

    // if not, get the next address to geocode from NSMutableArray and
    // remove it from list of addresses to process

    NSString *address = self.addresses[0];
    [self.addresses removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    // geocode the address

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];

    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        // do whatever you want for the individual geocode process

        // when all done, queue up the next geocode address

        [self nextGeocodeRequest];
    }];
}
```

Alternatively, and more complicated, you can use operation queues:

```
- (void)geocodeAddresses:(NSArray <NSString *>*)addresses {
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
    queue.name = @"com.domain.app.geocode";

    NSOperation *finalCompletionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        // do whatever you want when all done
        NSLog(@"done");
    }];

    for (NSString *address in addresses) {
        // create a block for the geocode request completion block

        NSOperation *geocodeOperation = [[GeocodeOperation alloc] initWithGeocoder:geocoder Address:address geocodeCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"placemarks = %@", placemarks);
            }
        }];

        // The final completion block is contingent on the completion of this geocode request completion block

        [finalCompletionOperation addDependency:geocodeOperation];

        // let's queue the geocode request

        [queue addOperation:geocodeOperation];
    }

    [queue addOperation:finalCompletionOperation];
}
```

Where, `GeocodeOperation.h`:

```
#import "AsynchronousOperation.h"
@import CoreLocation;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface GeocodeOperation : AsynchronousOperation

@property (readonly, nonatomic, copy) NSString *address;

- (instancetype)initWithGeocoder:(CLGeocoder *)geocoder Address:(NSString *)address geocodeCompletionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler) geocodeCompletionHandler;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

And, `GeocodeOperation.m`:

```
#import "GeocodeOperation.h"

@interface GeocodeOperation ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLGeocoder *geocoder;
@property (nonatomic, copy, nonnull) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, copy) CLGeocodeCompletionHandler geocodeCompletionHandler;
@end

@implementation GeocodeOperation

- (instancetype)initWithGeocoder:(CLGeocoder *)geocoder Address:(NSString * _Nonnull)address geocodeCompletionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler) geocodeCompletionHandler  {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.geocoder = geocoder;
        self.address = address;
        self.geocodeCompletionHandler = geocodeCompletionHandler;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)main {
    [self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:self.address completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        self.geocodeCompletionHandler(placemarks, error);
        [self completeOperation];
    }];
}

- (void)cancel {
    [self.geocoder cancelGeocode];
    [super cancel];
}

@end
```

And `AsynchronousOperation.h`:

```
@interface AsynchronousOperation : NSOperation

/// Complete the asynchronous operation.
///
/// This also triggers the necessary KVO to support asynchronous operations.

- (void)completeOperation;

@end
```

And `AsynchronousOperation.m`:

```
//
//  AsynchronousOperation.m
//

#import "AsynchronousOperation.h"

@interface AsynchronousOperation ()

@property (getter = isFinished, readwrite)  BOOL finished;
@property (getter = isExecuting, readwrite) BOOL executing;

@end

@implementation AsynchronousOperation

@synthesize finished  = _finished;
@synthesize executing = _executing;

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _finished  = NO;
        _executing = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)start {
    if (self.isCancelled) {
        if (!self.isFinished) self.finished = YES;
        return;
    }

    self.executing = YES;

    [self main];
}

- (void)completeOperation {
    if (self.isExecuting) self.executing = NO;
    if (!self.isFinished) self.finished  = YES;
}

#pragma mark - NSOperation methods

- (BOOL)isAsynchronous {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)isExecuting {
    @synchronized(self) { return _executing; }
}

- (BOOL)isFinished {
    @synchronized(self) { return _finished; }
}

- (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)executing {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    @synchronized(self) { _executing = executing; }
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
}

- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    @synchronized(self) { _finished = finished; }
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

@end
```

Comment: awsome! Saved my day!

Comment: @SwingerDinger - I don't know if you used my first example or my second one, but the second one wasn't really quite right, but I've remedied it to use proper asynchronous operations.

Comment: I've did used your second implementation and translated it into Swift 3.0. Worked like a charm.